I can't completely create a PyDev project in Eclipse
Whether I install PyDev as a plugin or as a web address from which to download the libraries in Eclipse, it always gives me the usual problem when I try to implement a project in Python. I can create the outermost part of the project, but when I need to create an internal Package to then create a module in python it won't let me create the Package, in the dialog box and in the top box it won't accept any Project Name including the one I need to enter. Has anyone been able to solve this problem?
I tried to update pip libraries via windows 11 cmd but nothing happened then once in the package build dialog box it accepted as source a folder of another project written in java but once I pressed the finish button that this time appeared nothing happened to the project, no package inside PyDev project was created

Can you show this by updating the question with a screenshot of that dialog when it's blocking you?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I was asking how to make a PyDev Project fully built correctly in its components and then executable. I thought there were problems in doing that and I showed them in answer 1 but then found the solutions I showed them in answer 2 in case anyone found the same difficulty with the Eclipse PyDev Plugin

In the new Package dialog box, I was selecting the entire name of the project while just clicking on the left arrowhead and it produced the following result:

And then I made the following steps:


But there is one more important thing to say: to get it to work, I had to download Python 3.12 from Microsoft Store and then go to Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter->Python and then remove the old Python.exe with the new by clicking new->first in PATH and paste the path to Python 3.12 downloaded with Microsoft Store. And then everything worked. The program ran correctly.

Your images are not accessible without access permission. Because links can go dead, it is better to add your images using the "Image" button in edit mode. Please consider updating your answer.
